# lists and dictinarys not working in an if/elif statement

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement, dictionary

heres the code:

```
def resetInv(inventory):
    if type(inventory) == list:
        inventory=[]
        return(inventory)
    elif type(inventory) == dict:
        return({})
    elif type(inventory) == str:
        return('nothing in inventory')
    elif type(inventory) == bool:
        return(False)
    else:
        return('not inventory type')
```

it works for str and bool, but not for lists and dictionaries.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve by this? The code in un-Pythonic in the extreme.

Comment: Why are you adding the string `none` to a list and a string when the dict and bool would imply that you want to return an "empty" object?

Comment: I am trying to achive a function that resets the inventory of a player, eg, if they died and loose all their items.

Comment: That was for testing, i wanted to know if that was the problem and must have forgotten to remove it. sorry.

Comment: what is "inventory"? It cant possibly be all of those things at the same time.

Comment: It seems to work for dictionaries and lists for me.

Comment: "inventory" is the variable that the function takes and contains whatever is set to inventory at the time, which may be any of those types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips:

- PEP8 recommends underescored_names for functions (instead of camelCaseNames)
- don't use type, if you must check type use the `isinstance` function
- checking for type is usually a code-smell in Python - use duck-typing or change the algorithm

This works for me:

```
>>> def reset_inv(inventory):
    if isinstance(inventory, list):
        return []
    elif isinstance(inventory, dict):
        return {}
    elif isinstance(inventory, str):
        return 'nothing in inventory'
    elif isinstance(inventory, bool):
        return False
    else:
        return 'not inventory type'


>>> reset_inv([1, 2, 3])
[]

>>> reset_inv({"a": 1})
{}

>>> reset_inv("foo")
'nothing in inventory'

>>> reset_inv(True)
False

>>> reset_inv(0.1)
'not inventory type'
```

The idiomatic way to write an inventory system would probably use a plain list or dict as a container of objects. Below I'm using strings, but you should probably write a class for inventory items with properties like value, weight and so on.

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self, items = None):
        if items is None:
            self.reset()
        else:
            self.items = items

    def reset(self):
        self.items = []

    def report(self):
        if not self.items:
            print("Your sac is empty.")
            return

        print("You have {} items in your sac.".format(len(self.items)))
        counter = Counter(self.items).items()
        for count, item in counter:
            print("{: >3} {}".format(item, count))


>>> inv = Inventory(['knife', 'rock', 'rock', 'cloth'])

>>> inv.report()
You have 4 items in your sac.
  1 cloth
  1 knife
  2 rock

>>> inv.items.append('coin')

>>> inv.report()
You have 5 items in your sac.
  1 cloth
  1 coin
  1 knife
  2 rock

>>> inv.items.remove('rock')

>>> inv.report()
You have 4 items in your sac.
  1 cloth
  1 coin
  1 knife
  1 rock

>>> inv.reset()

>>> inv.report()
Your sac is empty.
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I'm probably too stupid to understand the joke.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. i dont understand 100% of it but i know how to use it, which is the main thing.